# Purpose of the parentheses in the regex \b(\w+)(\W+\1\b)+

Tags: java, regex

What is the significance of parentheses in the following regex?

```
\b(\w+)(\W+\1\b)+
```

Please, explain because while changing the parentheses (either the order they are used or simply removing) is producing an error or not matching the solution.

Comment: Did you try google first? They're capture groups.

Comment: If you remove the parentheses, you will need to remove the `\1` as well

Comment: Ready any primer on regular expressions and then come back to ask a real question.

Comment: Just as an explanation, the primary source of down votes comes from "*the question does not show any research effort*" because a simple search for regex basics would already answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parantheses are needed because the `+` operator is connected to it.

For example if you have `a+` then it matches **one** up to **infinite** repetitions of the character **a**, like the word **aaaa**. If you use the `+` together with a group then the whole group is allowed to repeat, like in `(ab)+` which matches words like **ababab** but not **aaaabbb**.

The first parantheses are used as a **capturing group**. Its results are used in the second part where you have `\1` which matches the match of the first capturing group.

See this example at **regex101.com** which also explains the effects in detail: [regex101.com/r/3aLdDh/1](https://regex101.com/r/3aLdDh/1)

Comment: +1 good exlonation. also there is another good blogpost is:http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html